# Getting an error of "dotsCount must be superior to zero ,Failed assertion: line 31 pos 16: 'dotsCount >= 1'"

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

[The error i get after running my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6lQd.png)

> below is a sample of the code"

`  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
children: [
//slider section
GetBuilder(builder: (popularProducts) {
return Container(
height: Dimentions.pageView,
child: PageView.builder(
controller: pageController,
itemCount: popularProducts.popularProductList.length,
itemBuilder: (context, position) {
return _buildPageItem(position);
}),
);
}),

```
         //dots
        GetBuilder<PopularProductController>(builder: (popularProducts) {
     
          return DotsIndicator(
            dotsCount: popularProducts.popularProductList.length,
            position: _currPageValue,
             decorator: DotsDecorator(
              size: const Size.square(9.0),
             activeColor: AppColors.mainColor,
             activeSize: const Size(18.0, 9.0),
          activeShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
        ),
      );
    }),`
```

> The controller file

```
`import 'package:food_app/data/repository/popular_product_repos.dart';
 import 'package:food_app/models/product_model.dart';
 import 'package:get/get.dart';

 class PopularProductController extends GetxController {
 final PopularProductRepository popularProductRepository;

 PopularProductController({required this.popularProductRepository});
 List<dynamic> _popularProductList = [];

 List<dynamic> get popularProductList => _popularProductList;

 Future<void> getPopularProductList() async {
 Response response = await popularProductRepository.getPopularProductList();
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print("Got products");
  _popularProductList = [];
  _popularProductList.addAll(Product.fromJson(response.body).products);
  update();
  } else {}
}
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

This value must not be zero:

```js
GetBuilder<PopularProductController>(builder: (popularProducts) {
          print(popularProducts.popularProductList.length);
          return DotsIndicator(
            dotsCount: popularProducts.popularProductList.isNotEmpty
                ? popularProducts.popularProductList.length
                : 2,
            position: _currPageValue,
            decorator: DotsDecorator(
              activeColor: AppColors.mainColor,
              size: const Size.square(9.0),
              activeSize: const Size(18.0, 9.0),
              activeShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
            ),
          );
        }),
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this logic **

```
position:_currentIndex>images.length? _currentIndex=0: _currentIndex,
```